# The folding of ternary operator in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code is available ([demo](https://ideone.com/KQ444V))

```
f=lambda m, x:m and(x&1 and m.pop(0)or m.pop(0)[::-1])+f(m, x+1)
print(f([[4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8], [12, 11, 10, 9], [13, 14, 15, 16]],0))

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Here there is logic:

```
m.pop(0) if x&1 else m.pop(0)[::-1]
```

Please explain why when folding to the following view, is the code not executing correctly?

```
[m.pop(0)[::-1],m.pop(0)][x&1]
```

I don't know much about Python, will be grateful for any help, thank you.

UPD: If I change the logic, I get this result:

```
f=lambda m,x:m and([m.pop(0)[::-1],m.pop(0)][x&1])+f(m,x+1)
print(f([[4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8], [12, 11, 10, 9], [13, 14, 15, 16]],0))

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

PS. Code-golf (If this is important, the essence of the code is that it bypasses the two-dimensional array in the form of a snake)

Solution:

`[m.pop(0)[::-1],m.pop(0)][x&1]` => `(lambda: m.pop(0)[::-1], lambda: m.pop(0))[x&1]()`.

https://ideone.com/u6Qp4O

Comment: 1. That code looks horrible. 2. You forgot to tell us what the error is.

Comment: @timgeb, sorry, updated question.

Comment: `[m.pop(0)[::-1],m.pop(0)][x&1]` is not the ternary operator.

Comment: @user2357112, incorrectly applied the information [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855173/9908035)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the trinary `if` only evaluates one of its branch so only one `pop` call occurs. In your code there are two `pop` calls that both are evaluated.

```
[m.pop(0)[::-1], m.pop(0)][x&1]
```

To avoid that, if one must write it this way, and not using an a trinary `A if C else B`, one has to thunk, `lambda:`, each case and then after indexing the list of cases, call the case that was selected:

```
[lambda: m.pop(0)[::-1], lambda: m.pop(0)][x&1]()
```

One then could remove the common expression:

```
item = m.pop(0)
[lambda: item[::-1], lambda: item][x&1]()
```

Doing this before thunking, would result in:

```
item = m.pop(0)
[item[::-1], item][x&1]
```

This would not produce an error if item was slice-able. But it would uselessly  produce and discard a reversed copy of item. But if the item is say an `int` when x is odd and a `list` when even this would result in an error:

```
>>> 3[::-1]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Because all sub expressions in an expression are evaluated unless they have been delayed by a lambda.

A thunk is a term for a function that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The short-circuiting behavior is different between all three versions of the expression given (if certain elements of `m` are false).  The `a and b or c` idiom was commonly used before Python had a conditional operator, but is inequivalent if `b` is false.